# Remove SKU label from product reference select list

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to remove/hide the SKU value in the product reference widget (select list)? Because we don't want to show the SKU value to the editors.

[image: Product reference widget showing the SKU value in front of the product label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function <mymodule>_field_widget_options_select_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($context['field']['field_name'] == 'field_<fieldname>') {
    foreach ($element['#options'] as $key => $values) {
      $value = explode(':', $values);
      $element['#options'][$key] = trim($value[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps some one.

Comment: I see in your code that you're using explode() to get the value (i.e., label), but I was wondering if this label isn't available in the $element variable?

Answer (score 1):

In a custom module (or theme) you could implement [hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/7) and alter the labels of the options (i.e., stored in the `$element['#options']` variable). If I'm not mistaken your function would be `mymodule_field_widget_options_select_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context)`, where `mymodule` is your custom module (theme) name. Don't forget to check for which field you're altering the options, you can find this in `$context['field']['field_name']`.

If you don't want to write custom code, you could as an alternative use the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module in combination with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Hereby you can use the output generated by a view as an option list for the (entity) reference field (pointing to your product).

Comment: @Nagarjuna, did it solve your problem?

Comment: That worked @watergate. have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found Nagarjuna's code useful. I modified it to allow me to accommodate more than one field. In case someone can find it useful, I included the code below:

```
function <mymodule>_field_widget_options_select_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {

  $affected_fields = array('field_<field_1>','field_<field_2>','field_<field_3>','field_<field_4>');

  if(in_array($context['field']['field_name'], $affected_fields)) {

    foreach ($element['#options'] as $key => $values) {
      $value = explode(':', $values);

      if(isset($element['#options'][$key])) {
        if(isset($value[1])) {
          $element['#options'][$key] = trim($value[1]);
}
}
```

}
  }
  }